# conemu + Git bash + ssh Переход по ssh при старте conemu

Tags: git-bash

В настройках conemu в Tasks настроил, чтобы дефолтной консолью был Git bash. А можно ли сделать, чтобы при открытии, он автоматически соединялся по ssh с сервером т.е. когда включаешь conemu не только гитбаш открывался, но и выполнялась команда ssh username@hostname?

Comment: А в чем проблема-то? Выполняйте `ssh` вместо "git-bash", кто мешает?